# Migrating from Bamboo

Tags: git, deployment, bamboo, circleci

**TL;DR**

Moving away from Bamboo Cloud, what is the industry-recommended approach to deploying automatically to staging, and manually to production?

**Background:**

We are a small web agency. Early this year, we began using Atlassian's Bamboo Cloud. It fairly revolutionized our deployment system. When we merged our code into the `local` branch, it:

- pulls the latest code from GitHub
- runs our build scripts (compiling SASS, merging code together, etc)
- generates a `tar.gz` artifact
- pushes that up to staging

Usually once a week, upon UA testing and customer approval, we push code to production. With Bamboo, this involves selecting the staging deployment (always the latest one) and "promoting" to production (involving uploading that artifact to production and running the deploy scripts there).

We really liked knowing that what was tested on staging is *exactly* the same as what is on production, no exceptions; this is something I understand to be best practice. It was the same `tar.gz` file that was extracted in both places.

With this method, we do not have to have any SASS or compilation software in our production environment and we do not have any compiled assets in our repository.

Bamboo worked okay (it certainly had its flaws), except for the fact that Bamboo Cloud is being sunsetted.

Either I have become spoiled with Bamboo, or gone down a different road than everyone else with deployments as I cannot find a comparable solution.

**First question: is the way I am looking at builds/deployments the right approach?**

It seems most solutions (TravisCI, to some extent Circle CI) are all geared for running tests and immediately deploying. We would like to have the final deploy to production be a manual action.

**Second question: using CircleCI for the build/deploy to staging system, is there a recommended method for deploying to production when QA is finished?**

Comment: Just to clarify your question: you are intent on staying with a Cloud CI/CD/build solution? So Bamboo Server in-house (or as an EC2 instance) is not an option?

Comment: @Marakai: by not offering the cloud option anymore, I see that time is limited with their support for Bamboo (although I could be wrong). As such, we are wanting to step back and see what is the idea route to go. Thanks.

Comment: Well, the same article about sunset of Bamboo Cloud waxes on about Bamboo Server not just continued but expanded in the future. Yet, then they introduce Bitbucket Pipelines. I'm not sure what to make of it. Atlassian could be hands down industry leader, but their product and support decisions are byzantine, to say the least. But having used alternate products, I keep coming back: _when_ they work as advertised, they are best in breed.

Comment: I guess github Actions is the way for you to go now.. but yea.. this question probably just needs to be deleted?